# iOS: Find which library paused podcasts/music audio when users open our app

Tags: ios, twilio

**Problem:** When users open our app, the audio of Podcasts or Music would stop playing.

My app fetches below CocoaPod libraries

1. m*modal
2. YouTube Player
3. Twilio

Wondering how to find which library is stopping AV Session that's pausing the other apps' playback?

Edit: I can find by removing pods one by one. But, I have to make so many changes to be able to compile if I remove a Pod. Checking if there any better way with dev tools, if I can find what process/SDK is pausing the audio.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I don't believe the Twilio SDK should take over audio unless there is an active call. I can't tell you about the others though.

Comment: @philnash: Thank you for the confirmation.